# Load scripts in bootstrap modal when getting fragment of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm currently getting a fragment of a page and loading in bootstrap modal.

This fragment of page includes the jQuery required to load Google Maps but when the modal loads the content, all scripts are getting stripped so subsequently, the maps don't load.

Even if I directly insert the scripts inside the modal-body class, they still get stripped.

Is there a workaround to this at all?

What we're currently using to trigger the modal is:-

```
<a href="/stores .topclass" data-target="#StoresModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

I can provide further code in use if needed to answer accurately.

**=== Edit: Providing more code in use on request...**

So we're including a sitewide link that triggers bootstrap modal. The link that is triggering modal can be seen above and [here is the rest of the code in relation the modal](http://pastebin.com/N0ar063T).

What we wish to load in the modal is just a fragment of the page at `/stores`, all the code that is loaded at this URL can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/daU4Uvx2). From this page though, we only really wish to load everything inside .modal-container on line 192 but as necessary scripts reside outside of this div in the same file, we aren't capturing this when we try to load in modal. So previously, our modal trigger looked like:-

```
<a href="/stores .modal-container" data-target="#StoresModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

This then led us to try and just wrap entire file content inside div and call it's contents as the fragment of page in modal so that we can pull the necessary scripts required to load #map_canvas but alas, all scripts are stripped out of modal...

Hope this gives greater explanation into what we're trying to achieve.

**=== Edit 2: We've actually fixed this via a workaround but it was a mammoth job so will post answer as soon as I can...**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code to load view on boostrap modal :

```
 $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $(url).modal('open');
            } else {
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $(data).modal();
                }).success(function() { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });
            }
        });
```

With the following trigger :

```
<a href="new" role="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="btn btn-success" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="text here" data-toggle="modal" alt="text here"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> </a>
```

By using this method you will ensure that all you script will be loaded when your modal will display. This is only this workaroung that I found to correctly showing my modal.

Everything that I have to show on my form (**new.html**) will be displayed perfectly.

Thus, I suggest that you put all you releavant code to `Google Map` on the page corresponding to `/stores`.

**Edit** 
You trigger should be :

```
<a href="/stores" class="topclass" data-target="#StoresModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

Instead of :

```
<a href="/stores .topclass" data-target="#StoresModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>`
```

**Edit2**

The problem that I see, is that you modal inclusion do not get the JS files because these are not within your inclusion section. I'm not a PHP expert, but here is to option that you might try :

*Option1* (not very clean)

You can add `<script>Google Map required JS File</script>` tag inside the `<div class="modal-container"></div>` but you will get duplicate  tag for the same JS file.

*Option2* (Might be possible ?)

Create new file and add your section `<div class="modal-container"></div>` with your required JS files.

Replace the line 192 by including your new file and call your modal by passing your current store object in order to display your information in the modal.

Let me know if its help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All of the scripts and necessary jQuery are all already on the page corresponding to /stores already. In relation to your trigger suggestion in your edit, if I change it to what you suggest, it loads the entire page at /stores rather than the fragment of the page inside .topclass.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, did you set height and width on the gmap div ? Can you show me more code ?

Comment: Yes, the Google Maps just isn't loading purely because the jQuery it relies on is not being loaded through the modal with the canvas. Sure, I've edited the question providing links to full code relating to this scenario via pastebin though due to the amount of code. Thanks.

Comment: The entire file is within `.topclass`, everything is within the modal inclusion. As I said in original question, including any `<script>` inside `.modal-body`, whether directly or within class fragment, gets stripped. Your solutions don't help the fact that by whichever approach, the modal strips scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Has StackOverflow changed your code?

```
<a href="/stores .topclass" data-target="#StoresModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

You have the classname within the href? This could be part of the problem.